# winbio.dll freezes if called through python (WBF)

Tags: python, windows, wbf

I have started coding a python wrapper for the windows biometric framework. My python script should allow developers to access biometric sensors via the winbio.dll File. (Windows Biometric Framework)

I use `ctypes.CDLL("path to winbio.dll")` to call the necessary functions.

Firstly, I call the `WinBioOpenSession()`.

Secondly, I call

```
self.unit_id = ctypes.c_ulong()
ret = self.lib.WinBioLocateSensor(self.session_handle_ptr.contents, ctypes.byref(self.unit_id))
```

but the code execution freezes and doesn't respond.

I can successfully enumerate the biometric sensors attached to the system.

I use Windows 11.

A detailed version of the code can be found at the public github repository.

https://github.com/IamPekka058/py-winbio/tree/development-iampekka058/src/py_winbio